# .waitForElementVisible is unresolved function in Nightwatch template project

Tags: javascript, json, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, selenium-server

I have followed steps from http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted. 
And in my test file I have next code from http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
    browser
        .url('http://www.google.com')
        .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
        .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
        .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
        .click('button[name=btnG]')
        .pause(1000)
        .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
        .end();
        }
};
```

Also, this is how my package.json looks like.

```
{
  "name": "try_nw",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "try_nightwatch",
  "main": "nightwatch.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "node nightwatch -e chrome"
},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "bower": "^1.8.2",
  "chromedriver": "^2.34.0",
  "geckodriver": "^1.10.0",
  "nightwatch": "^0.9.19",
  "selenium-server-standalone-jar": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

And My nightwatch.json

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

    "selenium" : {
  "start_process" : true,
"start_session" : true,
"server_path" : "bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar",
"log_path" : "",
"port" : 4444,
"cli_args" : {
  "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "bin/chromedriver.exe",
  "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "",
  "webdriver.edge.driver" : ""
 }
},

"test_settings" : {
"default" : {
  "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
  "selenium_port"  : 4444,
  "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
  "silent": true,
  "screenshots" : {
    "enabled" : false,
    "path" : ""
  },
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "acceptSslCerts": true,
    "chromeOptions" : {
      "args" : ["--no-sandbox", "--start-maximized", "--disable-infobars"]
  }
  }
},

"chrome" : {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "acceptSslCerts": true
  }
},

"edge" : {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**But, when I run the test, the blank tab of chrome opens and console shows next output.**

```
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  15024

[Googletests] Test Suite
============================

Running:  Demo test Google

× Timed out while waiting for element <body> to be present for 1000 
  milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"

at Object.Demo test Google (E:\JS\Try_NW\tests\googletests.js:6:14)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)


FAILED:  1 assertions failed (5.972s)

 _________________________________________________

 TEST FAILURE:  1 assertions failed, 0 passed. (6.088s)

 × googletests

- Demo test Google (5.972s)
Timed out while waiting for element <body> to be present for 1000 milliseconds.  - expected "visible" but got: "not found"
   at Object.Demo test Google (E:\JS\Try_NW\tests\googletests.js:6:14)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)


 Process finished with exit code 1
```

**So,** <.waitForElementVisible> **is not defined. Can anybody suggest a decision?**

Comment: Where does it say that `waitForElementVisible` was not defined? o_O

Comment: @Tomalak WebStorm underline this and say <Unresolved function or method vaitForElementVisible()>.

Comment: I think you need to increase the timeouts. I just copied your test and the first `waitForElementVisible()` worked fine. It blew up on the one that is looking for the button when I ran it.

Comment: @OlehH It's not your script. It's Chromedriver. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is not the waitForElement, or anything else with your script per sae. The setValue right before that works differently with chromeDriver and your browser. Thats why you're seeing a tab open up and why the error message is about not finding the `body` element.

**If you update chromedriver you should be able to get your script to work.**

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/chrome-62-sendkeys-seems-to-be-causing-chrome-settings-help-to-open

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I run it on FireFox and it works! Have no idea why it didn't work with chrome. I changed next rows [`"webdriver.gecko.driver" : "bin/geckodriver.exe",`, `"desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "firefox",        "javascriptEnabled": true,     "acceptSslCerts": true       }`]

Comment: Probably it's bug with chromedriver https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1329

Answer (score 0):

There is something else causing your test to fail. I was able to run your test with the same `1000 ms` timeout and it passed fine with a slight modification. You might want to try increasing the timeout of `waitForElementVisible()`. The following test passed for me without issue.

```
browser
  .url('http://www.google.com')
  .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
  .setValue('input[type=text]', ['nightwatch', browser.Keys.ENTER])
  .pause(1000)
  .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
  .end();      
}
```

Comment: I already tried to increase timeout, but no success. Page is still blank.